# d3.js select function does not display barchart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>!-->
</head>
<body>
        <div id="chart_container"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function(){

                    var dataObj = []

                    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        dataObj[i] = {
                            potenial: 5 + i,
                            actual: 12 + (2 * i),
                            latest: 9 + (i)
                        }
                    }

                    console.log(dataObj)

                    // Create variable for the SVG
                    var svg = d3.select("#chart_container").append("svg")
                            .attr("height","50%")
                            .attr("width","50%");

                    // Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to rectangles for bar chart
                    svg.selectAll(".bar")
                        .data(dataObj)
                        .enter().append("rect")
                            .attr("class", "bar")
                            .attr("height", function(d, i) {return (d.actual * 10)})
                            .attr("width","40")
                            .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 25})
                            .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 400 - (d.actual * 10)});

                })

            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I tried to use `d3.select(body)...` it displayed fine, but I wanted to put into my `div` with id `chart_container`. It seems like it's not selecting the div with the id correctly, but I don't know how to fix it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please check whether the SVG is created under the div('#chart_container') by inspecting the page or viewing the page source code?. Here I am able to view the bar chart.

Comment: Adding to the above, set some dimensions (height,width) to the chart as well. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/4yd8jbs2/)

Comment: @Shashank That did the trick. Thanks!